# Strange Java Servlet Filter-Mapping Behaviour

Tags: google-app-engine, servlet-filters, web.xml

I am using Eclipse IDE with Google App Engine plugin, and Guice. Running on the Dev Server, I've tried both of these in `web.xml` and the guice `MyServletModule  extends ServletModule`:

```
<url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
```

and

```
filter("/user/*").through(LoginFilter.class);
```

both seem to work for

```
http://www.domain.com/user/
```

BUT... neither seem to work for:

```
http://www.domain.com/user/myaccount.html
```

Any idea why? According to the docs, `/user/*` should work for both, right?

...I suspect it has something to do with the file itaself, as I can't seem to filter on `"*.html"` either.

**EDIT**: **Solved**. Sigh... I found this tidbit in the GAE/J docs: 
`"Note: Filters are not invoked on static assets, even if the path matches a filter-mapping pattern. Static files are served directly to the browser."`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this tidbit in the GAE/J docs:

```
Note: Filters are not invoked on static assets, even if the path matches a filter-mapping pattern. Static files are served directly to the browser.
```

Even though all the Java Servlet docs say you can do it, you can't do it in GAE/J.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this pattern works:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/myFile.html</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

.. so in case you specify a file probably it will be filtered!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, those native GAE constraints do work, well but I needed added custom checking of stored session data, which I do in the filter, which the constraints didn't give me. I simply ended up turning my static *.html into a *.jsp.